How to understand this "Neither have I so much of the infidel in me ..." etc?

Neither have I so much of the infidel in me as to suppose that He (the God) has relinquished the government of the world, and given us up to the care of devils; (to be continued below)

Q: I am having hard time understanding this line: So "infidel" means unbeliever, which is negated by "Neither". Does this mean this author believes that the God has relinquished the government of the world? This does not make much sense to me. Pleases help. Thanks!

and so I do not, I cannot see on what grounds the King of Britain can look up to heaven for help against us:...

Q: How to understand "and so I do not"? The syntax here is so strange.

By the way, this is Thomas Paine in 1776, in case anyone was wondering.

It is! I had lots of trouble reading it. Now I understand it better with the help from here.

This seems to have been improperly migrated.  Thomas Paine is not a modern author.

Answer 1:
Here, "Neither" negates (and reverses the order of) I have and adds a new negation to the one expressed in the previous sentence.
So much ... as to means enough ... to.
The author is saying I am not infidel enough to suppose etc., i.e. the author does NOT believe that the God has relinquished the government of the world.
Answer 2:
That syntax expresses not only A, but B even, emphasizing B. The author not only does not see reasons for [...], but they actually cannot see any, implying that there are none.

Pretry much, yes. "I do not [though I probably would if I did some research], I cannot see [yeah nah, even if tried, it's just not there!]..."
